# ¿Como le paso el valor de mis $_POST a la consulta para hacer un filtro?

Tags: php, php7

el caso es que estoy haciendo un filtro con php y he creaod un filtro por defecto, pero quiero que sean el valor de un POST para realizar las consultas. Este es el código:

```
$filters=Array("DNI"=>11000258,"Nombre"=>"mad","Localidad"=>"Salamanca","Fecha"=>"1970-02-21");
    try {
    
        $conexion=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=universidad','root','');

        $params= array();
        $arr_where=array();

        $sql='SELECT * FROM alumno';
        if (!empty($filters))
            $sql .=" where";
        if (isset($filters["DNI"]) and !empty($filters["DNI"]))
        {
            $arr_where[] ='  dni like "%'.$dni.'%"';
            $params[":dni"]= $filters["DNI"];
        }

        if (isset($filters["Nombre"]) and !empty($filters["Nombre"]))
        {
            $arr_where[] ='  nombre like "%'.$nombre.'%"';
            $params[":nombre"]= $filters["Nombre"];
        }

        if (isset($filters["Localidad"]) and !empty($filters["Localidad"]))
        {
            $arr_where[] ='  localidad like "%'.$localidad.'%"';
            $params[":localidad"]= $filters["Localidad"];
        }

        if (isset($filters["Fecha"]) and !empty($filters["Fecha"]))
        {
            $arr_where[] ='  fecha_nacimiento like "%'.$fecha.'%"';
            $params[":fecha"]= $filters["Fecha"];
        }
        $sql .= implode(" and ",$arr_where);
```

En principio esto funciona, pero me devuele una consulta de este estilo:

`SELECT * FROM alumno where dni like "%1%" and nombre like "%%" and localidad like "%%" and fecha_nacimiento like "%%"`.

Tengo las variables definidasc como por ejemplo: $dni=$_POST['dni], y así con nombre, localidad y fecha,
pero no se como inscrutarlo en esa parte del código para que no me cree la consulta con comodines vacios. Perdón por si lleva muchas partes de código pero no tengo mucha idea en esto y estoy empezando, muchas gracias por la atención.

Answer (score 0):

Si ya tienes los campos en un arreglo, ¿no serías más fácil solo recorrerlo y pegar los filtros?  El único problema es que tendrías que poner el nombre de los campos.

```
    $filters=Array("DNI"=>11000258,"Nombre"=>"mad","Localidad"=>"Salamanca","Fecha"=>"1970-02-21");
    $params= array();
    $arr_where=array();
            
    $sql='SELECT * FROM alumno';
    if (!empty($filters))
      $sql .=" where";
            
    foreach( $filters as $key => $value ){
      $arr_where[] = ' '.$key.' like \'%'.$value.'%\'';
      $params[":$key"]= $value;
    }
    
    $sql .= implode(" and ",$arr_where);
```